# Require registration to access a certain page

Tags: plugins

I would like to require mandatory registration on wordpress before a user accesses a page. How can I do?

Comment: Searching for "WordPress membership plugins" is a good start. (If you're looking for a way to do this yourself: What have you tried? What *specific* problems are you having? Also, please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/418254/edit) to include any relevant code samples.)

Answer (score 0):

Without more info, it's difficult to guide you specifically.
Perhaps something [here](https://presearch.com/search?q=wordpress%20limit%20user%20access%20post%20type) will help you to get going.